# Goldfish skin around the intestine area is gone and stomach looks to be caved in

Tags: health, aquarium, diseases, goldfish, water-parameters

This is my first time posting so I’m sorry if I made any mistakes with my post.

I think I’m going to lose one of my goldfish. About 2-3 weeks ago both of my goldfish (I only have 2) developed ammonia burn. I treated them with API Stress Coat and did a 10% water change each day for a week. That seemed to have worked. However, a few days later they both developed fin rot. I tried Melafix for 6 days and that seemed to have done absolutely nothing except make their fins worse. I also didn’t do any water changes as I was told not to while I was medicating them. By day 3 or 4 (of medication) one of my goldfish developed dropsy (or at least what I thought to be dropsy given what I read online). On day 7 I stopped using Melafix and did a 20% water change and this time I used aquarium salt. I found a lot of resources online and on YouTube and I decided to start off with a low dosage of the salt. For the first stage of the treatment I was told to use 1 tablespoon per 3 gallons of water. I have a 20 gallon (76 liters) tank so I did 6 tablespoons. Day 7, I did the same thing. Also on day 7 I decided to treat the goldfish that had dropsy, so I took him out of the tank and placed him in a bath that had Epsom salt. I put 2 teaspoon in a 2 gallon bucket and placed him there for 7 minutes. Then I took him out and placed him in a recovery bucket with 1/4 teaspoon of the salt for 5 minutes. Afterwards I took him out and placed him back in the main tank that had the aquarium salt. He didn’t seem to be stressed while I was treating him with both salts and both of my goldfish were active and eating. Today is day 8 and I woke up to this **(see pictures)**. His belly has shrunk and caved in. I think I may have done more damage to him. I have cried for days because of what happened to them but now I’m utterly devastated. I couldn’t stop crying. I wanted to help them but I made the situation worse. I also live in Canada so most of the medications that’s supposed to work are banned here. I ordered Kanaplex from Amazon.com and it’s supposed to get here on Oct 13th (that is if customs doesn’t seize it). I don’t know what to do anymore. Please help me. I’ve been so stressed out that I developed stomach pains and can’t seem to sleep either. Additional information:

**Tank parameters:**

- Ammonia - 0.25 ppm;
- Nitrites - 0.25 ppm;
- Nitrates - Between 10-20 ppm;
- Temperature - I don’t use a heater;
- pH - N/A.

Note: no matter what I can't seem to get any of the above levels to zero.

**What type of filtration are you using?**
Aqua Clear power filter, the one for 20 gallons.

**How long have you had the fish?**
8-9 years.

**Have you added anything new to the tank?**
There are no décor nor plants in the tank. I did add new substrates and that’s when the ammonia burn began.

**What kind of food have you been feeding your fish?**
Stopped feeding my goldfish flakes and switched to Repashy since June of this year. They love it and have gotten so much healthier from eating it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi welcome to Pets, I repaired a few things in the formatting of your post by including line breaks where I assumed you intended them to be, etc. I am so sorry for this to be happening to your fish.

Comment: If the health of your animal is at risk, you should not wait for strangers from the internet answer your question. You should see a vet! I wish you all the best for your goldfish, they could become more than 25 years old if they stay healthy.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately my goldfish passed away. I learned a lot from my mistakes and I’m going to make sure I never repeat them again. I’m now going to focus and insure my other goldfish doesn’t fall to the same fate.